# floats and wrong parent width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a parent div with few child divs inside. Both have float left. Problem is when a child divs breaks to next line, parent div get a wrong width.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class='parent'>
<div class='child'></div>
<div class='child'></div>
<div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.parent{
float:left;
border:1px solid black;
}

.child{
margin:1px;
float:left;
width:300px;
height:50px;
border:1px solid black;
background:#65AEF1;
}
```

Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FDGqR/1/

As you can see, parent div got extra width. How can I force parent div to take exactly the width that childs really take?
[image]

Comment: Just add `width: 274px;` or do you want it to be in automatic when you adjust the width of the child?

Comment: There is a good chance what you want can't be done with CSS alone due to CSS flow intricacies.

Comment: @FriedBitz yes, I want it to be automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using media queries..

Just add the following code to your css:

```
@media (max-width: 840px) {
    .parent {
        width: 548px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
    .parent {
        width: 275px;
    }
}
```

You may need to set the above fixed widths for better design.

Even I am new to this.. so let me know if something goes wrong :)

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDGqR/22/)

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants. He wants the parent to shrink to fit the contents at any width.

Comment: @j08691 I am shrinking the parent by giving fixed width which is approximately multiple of `270` (_because of margin and border_).

Comment: This is not a quite I wanted, since I need to add a few media query statements, but so far this is seems to be the only solution of this.

Comment: If my window width is between 550 and 840, there's still a big gap similar to the image in the question.

Comment: @j08691 Working fine here on firefox, chrome and IE10 on Windows 8. Not sure.. maybe differing with PC.

Answer (score 1):

You could also set `percentages %` for `width`

```
.child{
   margin:1px;
   width:33%;
   height:50px;
   border:1px solid black;
   background:#65AEF1;
}
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDGqR/21/), if this is what you wanted.

Comment: No, sorry, child blocks needs to be float left to be in one line.

Comment: Oh he needs them to float to the left. I thought you needed the main wrapper to contain them.

Comment: @cleverketchup if that's what you want then the code your provided works, the only reason they are not displayed inline, is because the width of the browser isn't enough if you expand the browser it will contain and the child blocks will display inline

Comment: no, those child blocks are fixed width and I can't make them 33% width or whatever. More of it, on small-sized screens it is still have an empty space at the right.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

With the use of clear the parent div will take only the width of the two child divs

Comment: Yes, if you had `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` in between each div tag it works :) EDIT: or even better, add it to the CSS of the child like this `clear:both;`

Comment: Putting clear both to class child is wrong. It won't do what the OP wants

Comment: So he wants the blocks to move. But not to show any bigger parent before it is space enough for child to fit there?

Comment: The idia was to put child blocks in one line, and if there is no space for them - they should break to next line. It is matter of different monitor sizes, so at small sizes they placed in three lines, in full hd monitor - they are in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you also just set the .parent width to 610px (double the child width plus a little room for the margin) and then you would have two columns of .child divs?

.parent{width:610px;}

Comment: And what happens if the window is re-sized?